# IOS messages - contacts with both IOS and text messaging

Tags: ios, contacts, messages

So my kids all have "dumb" phones and iOS devices (iPods, iPads). Currently, I only have one contact per person, with both their iOS device and regular phone number as part of their contact.

Unfortunately, I can't tell if I'm getting a message from their phone or iOS device. If they are on their iOS device, I can send them links, images, etc... but if their are on their phone, I can only send text messages.

Apart from creating 2 contacts for each person (one for their phone, one for their iOS device) is there any other way to tell these apart?

Comment: Not quite sure that’s what you’re asking, but the background of a text message is green text messages while its blue for iMessages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your children have iMessage turned on `Settings.app > Messages > Turn iMessage *on*`, you can determine which device you are messaging based on the **color** of your message bubble backgrounds or, in your specific example, the "Send" button color (while typing):

**Green** = non-iOS dumb phones.

**Blue** = iOS devices.

Comment: I can't believe I never noticed that before! thanks for the great explanation!